# Why is mission planner not reading my Lua script?

Tags: lua

Whenever I try to run my Lua script, right after the first function, be it defining a parameter, mission planner (ground control station of ardupilot), display an error message saying unexpected token.

```
function pr()
local altitude = vehicle:get_altitude()
  if altitude > 1 
  then
    abc:set_value(1)
    gcs:send_text("Above 1m")
  else
    abc:set_value(0)
    gcs:send_text("Below 1m")
  end
  
  return update, 500 
end

local abc = param:define_class("abc")
 abc:set_name("test")
 abc:set_description("This is a test parameter.")
 abc:set_value(1) 

 param:add_parameter(abc)
pr()
```

Here, right after the function, it displays an error message:

> `("SyntaxError: unexpected token 'abc'")`

Answer (score 0):

`abc` is shown in the `pr()` function before it is defined. This is likely because you're defining `abc` as a local variable.

Some suggestions to fix it:

- make `abc` a global variable by removing the `local` part. (I recall pico-8 auto defines variables that way)
- add the `abc` as parameter to the `pr()` function , like `pr(abc)` at both locations